# Find value -> sum for 90 cells -> drop -> repeat

Tags: vba, excel

I have this spreadsheet i am working on for awhile. Its basically attendance piece. End user keeps track of employees, if they showed up or not etc...

I have tired looking up loops but i couldn't figure out how to do what i am trying to do.

What i have in this excel.

A-D : Emp info
E-∞ : 1-3 Days/Dates; 4-∞ emp data (if they missed a day, values for that)

To get better understanding, see [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9sdn2mfj0v0krx0/TEST_Attendance.xlsm)

The data entered from E5 to xx thats where i am trying to get this vba working.

Anything the script detects first value either '1' or '2', start 90 days (cells) from there. And after 90, reset to 0. starting from 91 start search for '1' or '2' and do similar.

See the excel file for better understanding. If it doesn't make sense, ill be happy to simplify.

Thank You

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? Why 90 days? What happens if an employee joins the company in the middle of a 90 span? Is that the last 90 days or fixed 90 day windows? What does '1' or '2' signify?

Comment: Well its 90 days only if there an event for that employee. If you see the excel file, you'll see '1' or '2'. So any time if an employee is late or didn't show up, he/she will have '1' or '2'. And from that day it'll start his/her 90 days. If they don't any event, nothing happens to them. Its fixed 90 days windows. '1' or '2', if an emp came late to the work; took longer lunch, etc... so employee could have 2 occurrence in 1 day. Thats why.

Comment: So it's summed by row? Where do you want the sum printed? in Column D, but what if there are more than one 90 day period? Do you have anything written already?

Comment: Once the first 90 day period ends, column D will reset. But updated excel has last column that does sum from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient and clean way to handle this is to use a form of a [relational data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) because it can be done easily without using VBA code. You will have two simple tables in your spreadsheet, EmployeeInfo and AttendanceRecords. Your Employee info will look something like this

```
Emp#    Name    Craft           # In 90 Days    NumOf2s NumOf1s
1       EMP 1   SM Site Manager 0               0       0
2       EMP 2   SM Site Manager 1               0       1
3       EMP 3   SM Site Manager 0               0       0
4       EMP 4   SM Site Manager 0               0       0
5       EMP 5   SM Site Manager 1               0       1
```

The last three columns are calculated from the AttendanceRecords table. This table is going to be variable size but this way you only need to store the important data (When employees actually got marks). It will look like this.

```
Emp#    Date        Days    Count
1       12/1/2013   122     1
3       1/1/2014    91      2
2       2/1/2014    60      1
5       2/15/2014   46      1
```

You can have multiple entries for the same day and the same employee. The important thing is that we only need one entry per infraction (NOTE: In order to do this in a proper database type model, each attendance record should also have some kind of incrementing totally unique ID (like employees), but we can forgo that for this application).

You enter in the employee number, the date, and the count. The "Days" column then auto calculates the age of the record with the following formula:

```
=TODAY()-[@Date]
```

NOTE: If the `[@Date]` notation does not look familiar, this is because it deals with Excel Tables. I recommend you [read up on those](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-excel-tables-HA010048546.aspx) if not already familiar.

So now we have the age of each record. So back on the EmployeeInfo table, we use the following formula to get all AttendanceRecords that apply to Employee x for the last 90 days

```
=SUMIFS(AttendanceRecords[Count],AttendanceRecords[Emp'#],[@[Emp'#]],AttendanceRecords[Days],"<=90")
```

You can now also use some simple formulas to get the other columns I pointed out, including the number of 2 count in fractions or the number of 1 count infractions:

```
=COUNTIFS(AttendanceRecords[Emp'#],[@[Emp'#]],AttendanceRecords[Days],"<=90",AttendanceRecords[Count],2)

=COUNTIFS(AttendanceRecords[Emp'#],[@[Emp'#]],AttendanceRecords[Days],"<=90",AttendanceRecords[Count],1)
```

There is a lot more data that could be gathered, including the date of the last infraction, total number of infractions for all time, etc. If any of the formulas or terms I used don't make sense or need more explaining, feel free to ask.

EDIT: If you want them automatically removed after 90 days, it would be relatively easy to write a VBA script to do this. It would also be easy to just sort the AttendanceRecords table on Days and delete all records that are older than a certain number of days. However, unless you see yourself adding hundreds of records a week, this really shouldn't be necessary. Also, If you want to write a Visual Basic form to enter in new infractions, that is definitely very possible, but another discussion.

EDIT: To respond to concerns about viewing when these issues happened, I will give you an example of a way to view the data in your tables. One of the advantages of excel tables is that the order of the records isn't as absolute as in a normal range, so we can sort, rearrange, and filter them to see what we need. So if you need to see all of the issues with employee 3, you just go to the Emp# column in the AttendanceRecords table, select the little arrow down button next to Emp#, uncheck 'Select All', and then check the '3', and then the only values I will see in the table are the ones from employee 3. I can then sort the 'Date' column by clicking its little arrow and selecting 'Sort Newest to Oldest'.

What it comes down to is that you can view ANY data you need to, and if you think through what you really need to see, you can set up your summary table (EmployeeInfo) to display enough data that you hardly ever have to look at the AttendanceRecords table. But if you need to, you can go into that table and do a manual sort (as I described above) very easily.

EDIT: To help add some of the functionality I've shown above to the askers current spreadsheet, I will show the current formula.

```
=SUMIFS($E5:$BR5,$E$3:$BR$3,">"&(TODAY()-90))
```

For EMP 1, this formula uses the employees row as the sum range. It then looks at the field of dates in the corresponding columns in row 3. If the date in row 3 is `> TODAY()-90`, then we will add it to the count. This will at least just look at the infractions for the previous 90 days.

Comment: This is great, but is it possible to work with the same file (the one linked into my main post)? They don't wanna create new one with 2 tables. Thanks

Comment: @SB89, I'm not sure I understand. You mean work with the current file you posted in your question? Reuse the current table? Only use one page?

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is the difference between an Excel file (commonly called a workbook), a single sheet in my workbook (commonly called a worksheet), and a table (an element on a worksheet).

Comment: Yeh i am sorry, should of made it clear. But i am still kinda confused. Is it possible you could demo it in temp file? Would make more sense.

Comment: @SB89, please try to download [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bc8qkd63oxrkda8/TEST_Attendance.xlsx). If you are unable to, let me know

Comment: the only problem i see in it is they keep track of it daily, the way i have it in the excel file i posted above. And in the file you posted, there is no way to tell when each occurrences happened.

Comment: @SB89, please see my latest edit to my answer. Essentially, you need to determine what kind of data you want to see and you can set up your tables accordingly. If you really need the raw attendance data, then you can just sort the AttendanceRecords table. I'm just showing you an efficient way to store and manipulate the data.

Comment: thank you for showing me efficient way but sometimes people don't want to change so i have to find a way to do it their way. Thats why i am trying to figure out.

Comment: @SB89, look at my latest edit to my post, I at least have a formula for looking at the previous 90 days and adding the infractions. As for removing old days, that is another issue that can also be addressed, but hopefully the formula I've added helps you out somewhat for the time being.